# Equal scale for x and y axis in a ggplot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have some ggplot plots in the Plotly function.
I would like the scale of x-axis and y-axis would be equal.
I used coord_fixed(below line), but it didn't work
coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, expand = TRUE, clip = "on")
please see my output(orange point), the x and y axis are not equal.
my desired output is like the attached figure , I need the distance between numbers on both axes would be equal, for example, 0.5 in the mentioned image.
Do you have any recommendations?
I need to mention, that I have a lot of input. the data is different for each of them, so the start number for all of them would be different.

```
output$fancyPlot <- renderPlotly({
   plot1 = ggplot(N, aes(x = Group1, y = Group2))+
              labs(title= input$TF_query1,
                   x= input$celltype1, y = input$celltype2)+
              geom_point(color = 'tomato')
            plot1 = plot1 + coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, expand = TRUE, clip = "on")

)}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yrrl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75AY0.png)

Comment: Adding some example data would make it easier to see what you're going for here and give a complete answer. But it sounds like you're looking for `ggplot2::coord_equal()`

Comment: I am pretty sure there are a ton of duplicate questions/answers for this, but the one I just used in the flag was the first hit to a search "equal coordinates ggplot" on SO, and the answers seem general/helpful for a wide variety of requirements around aspect ratio and scale.